# How to remove some elements in an object array using Lodash

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I'll just ask on how to remove some elements in an object array using lodash.

```
var fruits = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Apple', price: 55, qty: 3, status: 'ripe' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Banana', price: 55, qty: 4, status: 'ripe' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Pineaple', price: 55, qty: 2, status: 'ripe' }
];
```

How will I remove the qty and status in all object array so it will look like this

```
[
  { id: 1, name: 'Apple', price: 55 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Banana', price: 55 },
  { id: 3, name: 'Pineaple', price: 55 }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Without any library, you can use `map` and destructure the object.

```js
var fruits = [{"id":1,"name":"Apple","price":55,"qty":3,"status":"ripe"},{"id":2,"name":"Banana","price":55,"qty":4,"status":"ripe"},{"id":3,"name":"Pineaple","price":55,"qty":2,"status":"ripe"}]
var result = fruits.map(({qty,status,...r}) => r);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without using a library too.

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var fruits = [{ id: 1, name: 'Apple', price: 55, qty: 3, status: 'ripe' },{ id: 2, name: 'Banana', price: 55, qty: 4, status: 'ripe' },{ id: 3, name: 'Pineaple', price: 55, qty: 2, status: 'ripe' }];
let result = fruits.map(({status,qty,...rest}) => rest);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

> You can just iterate through the object using `forEach` and delete
>   the unwanted fields with the plain old `delete` operator.

This method cleans your current object, Without the need for a new object to be defined.

```
fruits.forEach((val) => {delete val.qty; delete val.status})
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala, I have added the explanation. I didn't do it earlier  because the operators I am using is basic and self explanatory.

Comment: @NarendraJadhav , I have added the explanation. I didn't do it earlier because the operators I am using is basic and self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that you **don't need** to use a library to effectively delete properties of an object though if you want to use **lodash** here is an example of how you would do that by using the `.pick` method:

```
let pickedFruits = [];
for (let i in fruits) {
  pickedFruits.push(_.pick(fruits[i], ["id", "name", "price"]));
}
```

where `pickedFruits` will be the new array of objects each having an `id`, `name` and a `price` property.